# SQL Server query to count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `Invitations` and `Users`, both table contain some emails.

I want to count those emails which are present in the `Invitation` table but not present in the `Users` table

**Invitation**

```
InvitationID    Email
-------------------------------------
    1           test@test.com
    2           someone@example.com
    3           test12@test.com
```

**Users**

```
UserName                  IsActive
-------------------------------------
test@test.com             InActive
sample12@sample.com       Active
test12@test.com           InActive
```

I tried it like this

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM Invitations, Users                                     
where Invitations.Email <> Users.UserName
```

I want like this

```
Count=1
```

Comment: So what is the specific issue here?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard - stop using it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're getting the wrong answer because you're counting the wrong thing.

Imagine two records, a and b in each table. a<>b and b<>a so you'll get 2, not the 0 you're expecting.

Try this instead

```
Select count(*) 
from Invitations
     left join Users                                     
     on Invitations.Email = Users.UserName
where Users.UserName is null
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select count(*)
from Invitation i
where not exists (select 1 from Users u where i.email = u.userName)
```

This is simplest way in my opinion, you can event read it: count all rows in `Invitation` table where not exists a row in table `Users` where `userName` is equal `email`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this one:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Invitation
WHERE Email not in (
    SELECT u.username
    FROM Users
)
```